# return update form page if form validation fails codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have one update form in Codeigniter.

I am validating it using form validation helper.My problem is how can i redirect user to same form when form validation fails? I need that update id as well in Url which I am passing.

Here is the code of calling same form

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $d['v'] = 'products/update';
                $this->load->view('template', $d);
                return;
            }
```

but it doesn't have that update id which I have passed.

http://www.example.com/products/update/10

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**In your controller:**

```
public function update( $id ){

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $d['v'] = 'products/update/' . $id;
                $this->load->view('template', $d);
                return;
            }

}
```

**In your View File:**

```
<form action="<?php echo $v; ?>" ..other attributes..> ....form elements....... </form>
```

Comment: try this:

<form action="<?php echo base_url() . $v; ?>" ..other attributes..> ....form elements....... </form>

Controller:
public function update( $id = ''){
..............
.............
}

Calling URL:

http://www.example.com/products/update/10